# Can we find the sum of a sorted array in O(logn) time?

Tags: algorithms

I have the following code:

```
arr = [2,3,4,5,6]
sum = 0;
   
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    sum = sum + arr[i];
print("Array has the sum of:"+str(sum));
```

So, I know the time Complexity is $O(n)$, but is there a way where we can calculate the sum using $O(\log n)$ time complexity?  I believe we can do it using a Binary search method.  I might be wrong, but can we actually do it in $O(\log n)$ time complexity?

Comment: Are all the elements of your array necessarily contiguous ? Like in your example ?

Comment: How did you conclude that this sum is in $O(n)$ time?

Comment: @Chickenmancer because we are incrementing and decrementing by a factor of 1. The number of iterations would be n/2 which is O(n)

Comment: @seboll13 yes, the elements in the array are sorted and continguos

Comment: Could you please edit the question so that you're… actually asking the question you want the answer to?

Comment: If your arrays are always contiguous, that is `[a1,...,an]` you'll only need to compute the length of the array, let's call it `m` and compute `a1*(m*(m+1))/2` So shouldn't you be able to compute this in constant time? Also, is this just a leet code question?

Comment: @PatrickStevens yes, edited!

Comment: @sss_coder then if the elements are contiguous, you have two cases: either your array has an odd number of elements and your sum will be the middle element times the number of elements, or if your array has an even number of elements, then the sum will be the two middle elements times $n/2$ where $n$ is the number of elements in your array. In both cases, the complexity is $O(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

The clear answer in the general case (sorted, but otherwise arbitrary) is "no."  You must visit each list value in order to compute the sum (the sorting does not help).  Thus it is an ${\cal O}(n)$ computation.

("Binary search" is irrelevant to this question.)

True, you can place *limits* on the sum of ordered list in ${\cal O}(1)$ time, but that wasn't your question.

Oh gee... if the elements are *contiguous* then this is an ${\cal O}(1)$ computation, as Gauss proved when he was 10 years old.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer "obviously not", consider the array $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_N$ which is sorted. Then suppose we had a way to compute the sum in logarithmic time. Since we can only visit at most $\log(N)$ of the elements, we did not visit at least one element $i_k$. Now set $i_k := \frac{i_k + i_{k+1}}{2}$ (or $\frac{i_{k-1}+i_k}{2}$ if $k = N$) to change the sum in a way that our algorithm could not detect.

(… and as David now notes, you left crucial assumptions out of the question. Please don't do that.)

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. I should have involved the assumptions.